# Using Ember & Handlebars with Django 1.4.2

Tags: django-templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to get Ember & Handlebars to work with Django 1.4.2 without much success.  I'm using Django-ember (latest version from here): https://github.com/noirbizarre/django-ember, Handlebars.js (1.0.rc.1) & Ember.js (1.0.0-pre.2).

Following the Django-ember instructions, I've added 'ember' to the installed apps in settings, placed {% load ember %} at the top of my template, and then placed this in a block:

```
{% handlebars "application" %}
   {{App.name}}
{% endhandlebars %}
```

where I've declared App with name variable in a js file.

The output is just blank however, no script tag is inserted as viewed in the browser console window (Chrome).

If I completely remove the javascript includes, the script tag is rendered - just with "{{App.name}}" left entact as expected.  So it looks like, Ember/Handlebars isn't rendering the template correctly.  Any ideas why?

A probably related quirk is that if I try

```
{% tplhandlebars "tpl-infos" %}
    {{total}} {% trans "result(s)." %}
    <p>{% trans "Min" %}: {{min}}</p>
    <p>{% trans "Max" %}: {{max}}</p>
{% endtplhandlebars %}
```

it throws a template error about {% trans being an invalid tag.  This can be fixed by including  {% load i18n %} but seeing as this isn't in the Django-Ember instructions, I'm inclined to think this is a sign of a bigger problem; perhaps it's not designed to work with Django 1.4.2.

**Update**
Seems it was actually rendering after all but that it's wrapping it in a div and putting it right at the bottom of the page where I hadn't noticed it.  So, now the next question is how do I get this back at it's orignal point in the html?

Comment: in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357697/how-to-resolve-conflict-between-embers-handlebar-and-django-template I see the guy using {% load ember %}, perhaps your are missing it ?

Comment: @sly7_7 {% load ember %} is already there, just above the {%handlebars

Comment: As in my update, turns out it was rendering correctly.

After rereading the Ember docs, seems I misunderstood how to use the templates - you describe them and then can append them to where you want them to display, rather than relying on them to display inline.